# importing the right module but getting an error in python

Tags: python

```
import sys
from subprocess import run, PIPE
import shlex
from src.detector_main import detect_main

def main():
    # print command line arguments
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        print(arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # main()
    print(sys.argv)
```

This is my main module. If you see the `from src.detector_main import detect_main`, it is supposed to import `detect_main` from `src/detector_main.py`.

In my `detector_main.py`, I have a bunch of imports,

```
import ast
import os
import fpdf
import sys
from Detector.class_coupling_detector import detect_class_cohesion
from Detector.cyclomatic_complexity_detector import detect_cyclomatic_complexity
from Detector.long_lambda_detector import detect_long_lambda
from Detector.long_list_comp_detector import detect_long_list_comp
from Detector.pylint_output_detector import detect_pylint_output
from Detector.shotgun_surgery_detector import detect_shotgun_surgery
from Detector.useless_exception_detector import detect_useless_exception
# from tools.viz_generator import add_viz

def detect_main(directory):
    # Get stats for files in directory
    stats_dict = get_stats(directory)
    ....
```

Running my main module gives me this error:

```
File "pyscent.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.detector_main import detect_main
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\proj\src\detector_main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Detector.class_coupling_detector import detect_class_cohesion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Detector'
```

I don't get this because I am following the exact path.

[image]

I don't get this because I am following the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you import the `Detector.class_coupling_detector` module in file that is in the same directory as *Detector* but your cwd **is not** the *src* directory.

Due to this you should either use absolute import `from src.Detector...` or relative import `from .Detector...`

[Here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) is some information about difference between this two ways to import

Comment: using the relative import `.Detector...` fixed that issue, but now i am getting this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.src'; '__main__' is not a package`

Comment: You must add a `__init__.py` (possibly empty) at the root of each package, here in `src/` and probably in `Detector/`

Comment: @Dawn17 you should add a `__init__.py` file to the root package(the directory above src). It can be empty